# Changing Electrical Outlets in Kitchen 1968 build

Tags: electrical

I am trying to change the old yellow outlets in my 1968 kitchen. The first outlet was simple, red wire and white wire, no ground wire.  My wires are not a cut pigtail but one long wire with the coating removed at the terminal point where it connects and loops around.  The seconds outlet is my worry.  The box contains 1 looped red and 1 looped white wire (exactly like the other outlet) but also an addition red and white as well.  These two addition wires were inserted into the back of the old outlet.  In the pic I’ve added the arrows to indicate where those second wires were. I cut them off when removing.  My problem is my new outlet will not accommodate those second wires, they don’t fit in the hole on the back the way the old outlet did. Can I just connect those second wires that wouldn’t fit into the holes in the back to the second terminal?  Red to brass and white to silver.  Then all 4 terminals would be in use?  This outlet is not for a major appliance like the frig, oven or dishwasher. [image]

Comment: Your new outlet is 15 amp go-to big orange box store and get the 20 amp receptacles and the wire stabs in back will be guaged to fit just fine. Kitchen outlets should be 20amp circuit s GFCI protected. The continuous loop is no big deal cut and wire line and load.

Comment: Ken:  Thank you for the information.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kitchen countertop receptacles (and bathroom and some others) must be on 20 Amp **circuits** for new installations. However, they do **not** need to be 15 Amp **receptacles**. In fact, I would bet that most homeowners in the US/Canada don't have a single device that actually requires a 120V 20A receptacle, unless they have a fairly serious workshop. That is by design - the manufacturers (of hair dryers, space heaters, toaster ovens, microwave ovens, blenders, etc.) know that for historical reasons many people don't have any 20 Amp receptacles, so they sell to the lowest common denominator - 15 Amp receptacles. In turn, NEC allows a 20 Amp circuit to have 15 Amp receptacles, provided there are at least **two** receptacles (which can be a standard 15 Amp duplex). This actually makes sense - the 20 Amp circuit with multiple 15 Amp receptacles allows you to use a high-current device (e.g., toaster) on a circuit and at the same time use some small (phone charger) to medium (blender) devices without tripping the circuit breaker - allowing > 15 Amp use at a time.

15 Amp circuits require 14 AWG wire, but can use 12 AWG wire (or larger, but don't waste your money). 20 Amp circuits require 12 AWG wire (or larger, but don't waste your money).

15 Amp receptacles are designed to handle 20 Amp **pass through** current. In fact, it is likely that most 15 Amp receptacles have absolutely no difference from 20 Amp receptacles except for the shape (T vs. straight).

Back to your specific problem: 3 wires (in/out of one loop, backstab of another). This is quite common. There are a few solutions:

- Unless separated for 1/2-switched or MWBC, or a GFCI (which has one hot line, one neutral line, one hot load, one neutral load), standard duplex receptacles have two screws for hot and two screws for neutral. So you can put the loop on one screw and the individual wire on the other screw.
- You can pigtail: Cut the loop (but only if that leaves a few inches of usable wire on each section - but which should be the case for a functional loop anyway). Use a wire nut to connect the two sections of the (former) red loop and the other hot wire and another piece of wire (12 AWG, black (or any color except green or white)) and connect that new wire to a screw. Similar (with white wires) for the neutral. That way you only have 1 hot and 1 neutral connection.
- Screw-to-clamp - Don't use the backstabs! With screw to clamp, you can normally have two wires under each screw. Cut the loop. Two wires from the (former) loop under one screw and the third wire under the other screw. Nice advantage is you don't have to worry about making a perfect "hook" - the wires go in straight!

Your hot wires are red. That is unusual, and indicates your wires are in conduit. If they are in *metal* conduit with metal boxes then you don't need separate ground wires. However, you still need ground *connections*. The better receptacles (typically the same ones with screw-to-clamp) will be marked as *self-grounding*. If they are, grounding is handled through the metal yoke making contact to the metal box. If they are *not* self-grounding, then you need to connect a ground wire to the metal box with an appropriate screw.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response.  I do have metal boxes and the wires are in metal conduit.  I will look for the self grounding receptacles.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. On each side of the duplex you have two screws and "holes in the back"l The "holes in the back" are connected to the screws on that side and they all have the capacity to carry the duplex rating. Keeping all the reds on one side and whites on the other side you will be just fine. Red to brass and white to silver is correct! Enjoy the kitchen update!

Comment: The holes in the back are commonly called backstabs and are notoriously known to fail after time so it's good that your new outlet didn't accommodate them. We would have said not to use them.

Comment: 15 amp receptacle is what the op has, the wires will fit a 20amp receptacle and the back stabs are fine as long as nobody removes and reinserts multiple times.op should have 20amp receptacle it's a kitchen.

Comment: Thank you for your the information.  Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You have the wrong rated receptacle s, get 20 amp  not 15 amp for your kitchen, 12 gauge wire is what you have , about thickness of a nickel , that's 20 amp. It's not supposed to fit the wrong receptacle.

iIf you really want it to be right install GFCI breaker or nstall GFCI as first outlet, cut the line put line in in line in and the feed to the rest in the load side. That makes it safe.

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Comment: 20 Amp **circuit** is required. But not 20 Amp **receptacles**.